# How to add a text on Homepage using module (code)

Tags: magento2, php, module

Need help writing a code for adding text on Homepage.
I'm running Magento 2 on localhost

Comment: Goto: `Admin -> Content -> Pages` find the `Home Page` and add the text in the `Content` section.